# what is wrong with the following sql on Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

The following sql was constructed by sqlalchemy and I don't understand what's wrong with it:

```
UPDATE my_table SET "level"=anon_1.rank FROM
    (SELECT
        my_table.id AS id,
        CASE my_table.employee_id
        WHEN @curType THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1
        ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := my_table.employee_id
        END AS rank
        FROM my_table, (SELECT @curRow:=0, @curType:=\'\') r
        ORDER BY my_table.employee_id, my_table.id) anon_1
    WHERE my_table.id = anon_1.id
```

The result is "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

Basically, I need something that would produce the same result as a window function but without using window function (I need the same query to run over mysql as well)

Can someone help me fix this query or construct a new query that will produce the same result and would work on both mysql and Oracle?

Comment: it may not like the missing close paren.  Ending with a semicolon also is the "correct" way to do things.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus: there is a lot more wrong with that statement than just the closing parenthesis

Comment: definitely, but what do you expect from procedurally created SQL?

Comment: "*that would produce the same result as a window function but without using window function*" - why would you want to do that? Any hack around that will be slow and not scalable. There is no way you get write a statement that does the same thing with the limited capabilities of MySQL and Oracle at the same time.

Comment: "*The following sql was constructed by sqlalchemy*" - looks like a bug in that tool then. Apparently they don't support Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the `@` character doesn't do what you think it does.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12002.htm